# SQL get name on the id from other table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

1.Table1

```
---------------------------------
| id_table1 | id_test1| id_test2|
---------------------------------
| 1         | 10      | 1       |
---------------------------------
| 2         | 20      | 3       |
---------------------------------
```

2.Table2

```
-------------------
| id_table2 | name|
-------------------
| 1         |name1| 
-------------------
| 3         |name3|  
-------------------
| 10        |name10| 
-------------------
| 20        |name20| 
-------------------
```

`id_test1` and `id_test2` have relation with table2 and I want to query only `name`, example

```
-------------------
| NameA     |NameB|
-------------------
| name10    |name1| 
-------------------
| name20    |name3| 
-------------------
```

in PHP I can solve loops but I'm interested to solve this only in SQL.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this query

```
select a.name, b.name 
from table2 as a, 
inner join table2 as b
inner join table1 as c
where c.id_test1 = a.id_table2
and c.id_test2 = b.id_table2;
```

Comment: I quite forgotten can immediately add 2 or more inner join and thanks for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name b.name FROM " + table2 +" a JOIN "+ table1 + " z ON a.id_table2 = z.id_test1 WHERE a.name ="+ "'"+given_ID(id_test1)+"'" and b.name ="+ "'"+given_ID(id_test2)+"'";
```